# Cannot log into migrated site

Tags: login, migration

I migrated a working Wordpress site to a sandbox server. Prior to importing the database I did a search and replace for the domain name.

example.com/wp-admin loads wp-login.php

Submitting form results in immediate reload of form.  No errors seen. When my user and pass were not accepted I attempted password reset but the email was not received and the form just rapidly reloads on submission.

I tested that changing blog name in options table resulted in new name displayed on login form. So definitely loading site settings from this database.

No other tables exist in database.

I edited user database row to set new email.  No mail received.

I added the following with verified user id to my functions.php

```
$user_id = 4;
$password = 'newpasswd';
$output = wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );
```

Still could not log in and observed that hashed password in database was in fact changed.  Having seen the change the `wp_set_password()` call was removed from functions.php

Enabled WP_DEBUG in wp-config.  Saw some plugin Notice level flags but no errors.

I changed plugins directory name and added a new empty plugins directory. No change.

Same with themes.

No more WP_DEBUG Notices seen so disabled again.

Emptied the .htaccess which had default WP rules plus Wordfence rules and re-uploaded.

Commented out the Wordfence .user.ini file which sets auto_prepend_file.  No change.

Tried multiple browsers.  No change.

Console does not show errors.

This screenshot shows network panel headers when submitting form.

[image]

Here is main network panel showing a 301 before a 200.  Thinking this may be relevant...

[image]

What should I try next?

Comment: How did you search and replace? If you just used a text editor, some of the data is likely corrupt as WP stores a lot of serialized information - if the new URL contains a different number of characters than the old URL, everything can go sideways fast. It's safer to use a db migration plugin which will handle serializing as well as the basic search and replace.

Comment: @WebElaine I did do the s// via a text editor but have now reloaded database from original export and just edited siteurl and home rows of options and issue remains the same

Comment: @WebElaine your point was well taken and I ended up wiping the lot and using UpdraftPlus to successfully migrate.  Thank you

Comment: Want to add your comment as an answer @WebElaine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you search and replace? If you just used a text editor, some of the data is likely corrupt as WP stores a lot of serialized information - if the new URL contains a different number of characters than the old URL, everything can go sideways fast. It's safer to use a db migration plugin which will handle serializing as well as the basic search and replace.